# No signing certificate "iOS Development" found: No "iOS Development" signing certificate matching team ID "************" with a private key was found

Tags: ios, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci

I am working on a CI/CD for an iOS project, i use `fastlane` & `Gitlab CI`, this is my lane in the `fastlane` which work on the local machine when i run the command bundle exec `fastlane` build:
lane :build do

```
 #increment_build_number
  update_code_signing_settings(use_automatic_signing: true, path: "XXXXXXXXXXX.xcodeproj")
  build_app(
    scheme: "XXXXXXXXXXXXX", 
    clean: true,
    silent: true,
    #skip_codesigning: true,
    skip_package_dependencies_resolution: true,
    #cloned_source_packages_path: "./dependencies",
    output_directory: "./build", 
    output_name: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.ipa", 
    configuration: "Release",
    #codesigning_identity: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    #export_team_id: "XXXXXXXXXX",
    #xcargs: "PROVISIONING_PROFILE_SPECIFIER=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
  )
end
when i run the build job in the gitlab ci:
stage: build
  script:
    - cd $HOME/workspace/iOS/attijarimobile-ios/
    - bundle exec fastlane ios build

it return this error : path.xcodeproj: error: No signing certificate "iOS Development" found: No "iOS Development" signing certificate matching team ID "XXXXXXXXXX" with a private key was found. (in target 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXX' from project 'XXXXXXXX')
```

I can't understand the source of the problem, because the build passed in local and do not in the `gitlab CI`

Comment: in local do u have the certificate somewhere as env variable or some other way

Comment: In local development, the certificate is located within the Keychain, which is a macOS utility for securely storing sensitive data. When initiating the build process either through Xcode or the terminal, they access the Keychain to retrieve the certificate and use it to sign the iOS project. Similarly, when running the command ```security find-certificate -a /Users/mbk-ci/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db```on GitLab CI, it displays the certificate, indicating that it's accessing the Keychain.